# Copy file in relative directories

Tags: bash

I have a lot of files with names in the same format – four alphanumeric characters, `.pdb`, and a digit – and I would like to copy them into corresponding directories.

For example, in the directory `home/Desktop/chain/file` I have these files:

```
1b47_biounit1.pdb
1ca9_biounit1.pdb
1ca9_biounit2.pdb
1ca9_biounit3.pdb
5tr6_biounit9.pdb
```

Now I have created a lot of directories under `home/Desktop/chain`; the names of the directories are:

```
1b47_A
1b47_B
1ca9_A
5tr6_2
```

I would like to copy the files in the file directory into the directories with the same base name.  The result would be this:

```
1b47_A -> 1b47_biounit1.pdb
1b47_B -> 1b47_biounit1.pdb
1ca9_a -> 1ca9_biounit1.pdb 1ca9_biounit2.pdb 1ca9_biounit3.pdb
5tr6_2 -> 5tr6_biounit9.pdb
```

I’m not very familiar with programming languages but I tried with this code:

```
cd home/Desktop/chain/file
for name in ./*.pdb; do
     for dir in "${name%.pdb}"*/; do
         cp "$name" "$dir"
     done
done
```

But I got a different and not desired result. Could someone help me please?

I use a script and I don't do this manually because there are many files and directories.

Comment: this:cp: cannot create regular file ‘./1b47_biounit1*/’: Not a directory
cp: cannot create regular file ‘./1ca9_biounit1*/’: Not a directory
cp: cannot create regular file ‘./1ca9_biounit2*/’: Not a directory
cp: cannot create regular file ‘./1ca9_biounit3*/’: Not a directory

Comment: And with you change is this:

Comment: cp: cannot create regular file ‘.././1b47_biounit1*/’: Not a directory
cp: cannot create regular file ‘.././1ca9_biounit1*/’: Not a directory
cp: cannot create regular file ‘.././1ca9_biounit2*/’: Not a directory
cp: cannot create regular file ‘.././1ca9_biounit3*/’: Not a directory

Comment: there is no string replacement for biounit

Comment: mmmm and? How I can modify it?

Comment: try `"${name%_*}"*/` (and in general do a *test || continue* in for loops)

Comment: It doesn’t work. It returns the usual error. But a different script than mine? I may have wrong several things . Like I said, I’m new at this.

Comment: you can use *echo* in front of *cp* for debugging purposes, or run the script with *sh -x script*

Comment: The problem is not running the script, the problem is that it does not work and I do not understand what is wrong. Could you suggest a new script?

Comment: `"../${name%_*}"*/` then maybe? debug your script yourself by analyzing what it does (like suggested with *-x* or *echo*)

Comment: cp: omitting directory ‘.././1b47_A/’
this is the result

Comment: please update your question with new code. best is below the original

Comment: or name in ./*.pdb; do     for dir in "${name%_*}"*/; do       echo cp "../${name%_*}"*/ "$dir";      done;  done

Comment: replace only "`${name%.pdb}"*/` (that one in the for loop, not in the cp)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62874856

Comment: Your filename description and the examples do not match.

Answer (score 2):

Hope it could help you.

```
cd home/Desktop/chain/file
for name in $(find . -type d -depth 1 | xargs -I {} basename {} | cut -c-4 | uniq); do
        for dir in $(find . -type d -depth 1 -name "$name*"); do
                cp $name*.pdb $dir
        done
done
```

Comment: you might interested in answer that question too https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/600931/how-i-can-check-if-the-a-certain-file-is-present-in-a-directory

Comment: There is nothing zsh-specific about that. So why `#!/bin/zsh`?